# How do I store values for specific tab with not domain, in a Safari extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

I am developing an extension for all browsers. For Firefox, we solved using an NSISessionStore object with a `setTabValue()` method.

How do I solve the same problem in Safari and Google Chrome extensions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I store values for specific tab for Chrome, and Safari extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859624/how-do-i-store-values-for-specific-tab-for-chrome-and-safari-extensions)

Answer (score 1):

In Safari: you have a tab object, for example:

```
var myTab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab;
```

What I do if I want to store a value for that tab is simply:

```
myTab.something = someValue;
```

You can do something similar in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome each tab has ID, so you can use that as a key.

In Safari you can identify tabs by using `SafariBrowserTab` object as a key .