# How do I store values for specific tab for Chrome, and Safari extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

I am developing an extension for all the browsers. How do I store tab specific values in the session? I solved this problem in Firefox with an NSISessionStore object. In Safari and Google Chrome, I used SessionStorage; this object stores values for a specific tab with a specific domain. I want a solution for how to store values for a specific tab.

Comment: Can you please rephrase this as it 's hard to understand what you actually want to know.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to manage data throughout the life of a tab you can simply create an object for the tab when it's created and delete it when it is closed.

```
// Create data store
var tabDataStore = {};
// Create listeners
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
    tabDataStore['tab_' + tab.id] = {
        urls: []
    };
});
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function (tabId) {
    delete tabDataStore['tab_' + tabId];
});
// Save something against that tab's data
function saveUrl(tab) {
    tabDataStore['tab_' + tab.id].urls.push(tab.url);
}
// Load something from tab's data
function loadOriginalUrl(tab) {
    tabDataStore['tab_' + tab.id].urls[0];
}
```

However, this is all an assumption and you may want something completely different. Also, it depends when and what exactly you want to store.

Further information on tabs can be found in the [official documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html).

If you want to persist anything you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

Comment: Note that this solution is Chrome-Specific.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to do it, though not ideal as it would look messy would be to store the values in the URL hash

say the URL of the tab was http://whatever.com/
you could store the value in the hash like so
http://whatever.com/#value1=12&value2=10&value3=15212

there will also be a problem if the website uses the hash object for anyhting such as "in page" anchors, or ajaxy type stuff

Answer (score 0):

Safari Answer

In your global page save directly to the tab.. so for instance on message from injected script

```
// global page
safari.application.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    switch(event.name){
        case "saveData":
            event.target.page.tabData = { data: myData }
        break;
        case "getData":
            event.target.page.dispatchMessage("tabData", myData);
        break;
    }
}, false);
```

-

```
// injected page

// first save data
safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("saveData", {firstname:"mike", age: 25} );

// setup listner to recevie data
safari.self.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    switch(event.name){
        case "tabData":
            // get data for page
            console.debug(event.message);
            // { firstname: "mike", age: 25 }
        break;
    }
}, false);

// send message to trigger response
safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("getData", {} );
```